# Stable pairing algorithm with only set of priorities?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Consider the [Stable Marriage Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem):

> In mathematics and computer science, the stable marriage problem (SMP) is the problem of finding a stable matching between two sets of elements given a set of preferences for each element. A matching is a mapping from the elements of one set to the elements of the other set. A matching is stable whenever it is not the case that both:

The stable marriage algorithm is a complete and optimal solution to the stable marriage problem.

However, I have a different, yet similar, problem. I need an algorithm that, when given a pair of elements, will find a stable and optimal pairing between them. The catch is that in my problem, only **one pair** of the elements has preferences, **the other side doesn't care**.

To bring a real life analogy to this, consider the problem of job assigning:

> In a group software engineering project, there are m employees and n
>   different tasks  to be accomplished. Each employee has his/her own
>   experiences and expertise so cares  about which task he/she gets to
>   work on. The manager asks each employee to write down a preference
>   list of the tasks, ranking each task. What would be an algorithm to
>   pair  each employee with ONE task, so that employee satisfaction is
>   maximized.
>
> If n > m, there will be left over tasks, this is ok, they can be
>   completed by interns  or contractors.

**Note:** one easy way to quantize employee satisfaction is by simply adding up the rankings of the jobs that each employee got.

**For example**: if employee a got his first choice, and employee b got her third choice, and employee c got his 2nd choice, the overall employee satisfaction is `1 + 3 + 2 = 6`.

Minimizing this number will maximize satisfaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). The textbook example is transportation: *n* number of packages need to be transferred while there are only *m* drivers(*m* < *n*) and where there is a cost associated with each transport. I believe your problem can be cast into that form.

The most common algorithm to solve this is the Kuhn-Menkres algorithm, also known as the Hungarian algorithm. This algorithm is available online in many programming languages, so google and go forth!

Comment: Awesome, this seems to be a great way to approach my solution. I'll look into the Hungarian.

Comment: I'm assuming that after we processed each row (by subtracting the minimum value from all elements), we treat the assignment as a CSP (constraint satisfaction problem)? Or is there a simpler way to approach that step?

Comment: @RazorStorm: I don't think you fully understand the algorithm. It doesn't stop until each row and each column has a zero and therefore yields a solution. But furthermore, unless this is for educational purposes, you should search for an implementation, rather than creating it yourself, because debugging this fairly complex algorithm takes time, time and then some more time.

Comment: It's for an educational purpose. I was asked this question by a friend and am trying to figure out how I would go about solving it. I'm currently looking at open source implementations of the algorithm and trying to understand how it works.